# ActionBarCompat with Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar shows white title text but black spinner text

Tags: android, colors, spinner, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using the ActionBarCompat and both Title text followed by a spinner in the ActionBar. I'm using theme Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar which should show white text on a black background. The title text does show in white but the spinner text appear in black. Switching the theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light has both as black text on white. Can anyone suggest how I can get white text into the spinner? I've seen suggestions for ActionBar and ActionBarSherlock but can't get them to work on ActionBarCompat. I've tried styles as per the following without success:

```
    <style name="SBRRTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SBRRCustomDropDownItemStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="SBRRCustomDropDownItemStyle"> parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/SBRRCustomDropDownItemTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="SBRRCustomDropDownItemTextStyle"> parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The activity definition in the manifest is:

```
        <activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:name="com.example.actionbar2.RaceResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/action_raceresults"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Further information, after testing with a Nexus-S emulator and on a physical Galaxy S2, both running JellyBean, the problem with  the spinner appearance in the ActionBarCompat itself only shows up on my development device, a Galaxy Y running 2.3.5 Gingerbread. Also shows on a 2.3.3 AVD.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set listadapter as **R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item**

Example:

```
Context context = ab.getThemedContext();
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> listAdapter =
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.locations, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

listAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

The support library has a layout for drop down spinner item.

@Kuitsi comment is correct. Use the same layout for dropdown view and item.

Comment: Thanks, that has partially solved the issue, in that the dropdown from the spinner now shows the items as white on black, but the initial state of the spinner (i.e. before the list of items is dropped down) is still black on very dark grey. Any further suggestions welcome.

Comment: Did you set the theme to activity like                   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" or something similar??

Comment: Hi Tarun, I've included the manifest definition of the activity above. Everything looks correct on the ActionBarCompat with white text on the very dark grey background other than the spinner text which is black.

Comment: Hi Tarun, note further info above, the problem only shows on 2.3.5, not on JellyBean

Comment: I couldnt find any support resource for spinner. Looks more like a bug to me.

Comment: I got the initial value to white when I used `R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item` also in ArrayAdapter

Comment: To be clear: use same layout resource in `createFromResource` and `setDropDownViewResource`

Comment: saved my time! it's time migrate from ABS to ABC!! we also make sure we are calling getSupportActionBar() than getActionBar().